# How to hover a text inside a box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, html-lists

I would like to ask two questions.
I have a box in my bootstrap, and when i hover over it, it's color becomes purple and the word "Join" inside of my box, becomes white.
The problem is that the text Join is white only when i hover over the specific text and i want it to stay white as long as i am inside the whole box, not only when i am over the word "Join".
If i move my mouse a little bit to the right or to the left of the word Join and while i am inside the box, the word Join is not white any more but it is grey again, as it used to be, before i hover over it.

---

### Update: Thanks @sanriot for the answer to my first question! It worked!

And my second question is that when i resize the page, and the hamburger menu appears, the alliance of my menu is not on the same vertical row.
The Join box is a little bit to the left as you can see on picture number 1.
How can i align the Join with the rest of my menu?

This is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Aurora</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a
            class="navbar-brand"
            href="Aurora.html"
            target="_blank"
            style="color: rgb(98, 99, 104)"
          >
            <b>Aurora</b></a
          >
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#" style="color: purple;"
                ><b>
                  <font
                    onmouseover="this.style.color='rgb(196, 6, 152)';"
                    onmouseout="this.style.color='rgb(128, 0, 128)';"
                    >Aurora Pro</font
                  ></b
                ></a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" style="color: #95979D"
                ><b
                  ><font
                    onmouseover="this.style.color='#660066';"
                    onmouseout="this.style.color='#95979D';"
                    >Become An Influencer
                  </font></b
                ></a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" style="color: #95979D"
                ><b
                  ><font
                    onmouseover="this.style.color='#660066';"
                    onmouseout="this.style.color='#95979D';"
                    >Sign In</font
                  ></b
                ></a
              >
            </li>

            <li class="centeredjoin">
              <a class="joinclass" href="#" style="color: #95979D">
                <b> Join </b></a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}



li.centeredjoin {
    
    border: 1px solid ;
    color: rgb(123, 124, 129);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
   
    
}  
.joinclass {
    padding: 0em !important;
    margin: 0;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

[Picture Number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBIEX.jpg).

Comment: the visual that you show has nothing to do with the sample code that you show. We cannot really help you in this case because your question is incomplete https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **it makes no sense !**

  either you choose **bootstrap_3** or you choose **bootstrap_4**, but **not both**.

ditto for jQuery, either you choose **jQuery (with AJAX)** or you choose **jQuery.slim, (without ajax)** but **not both**.

Answer (score 0):

Change style attribute to stylesheet. style attribute's style always overwrite stylesheet styles.

You can know more details that specificity on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```css
.joinclass {
  color: #95979D;
}

a:hover {
  /* Only the word Join becomes white */
  color: white !imporntant;
}

.centeredjoin:hover {
  /* The whole background becomes purple */
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li class="centeredjoin">
    <a class="joinclass" href="#">
      <b> Join </b></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo Because bootstrap's JavaScript file requires jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the selectors in CSS:

```css
a {
  color: #95979D;
}

.centeredjoin:hover {
  /* The whole background becomes purple */
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
}

.centeredjoin:hover a {
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<li class="centeredjoin">
  <a class="joinclass" href="#">
    <b> Join </b></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the below code in which only hover property is used and you can easily understand.

```css
.rightmenu{
 width: 25%;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
}

.rightmenu ul{
    display: inline-flex;
 margin-left: 200px;
}

.rightmenu ul li{
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px; 
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.rightmenu ul li i{
 margin-top: 12px;
}

.rightmenu .fa{
 margin-right: 6px;
}

#firstlist{
 color: orange;
}


.firstlist, .rightmenu ul li:hover{
    color: orange;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type=" text/css" href="test.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="rightmenu">
    <ul>
     <li id="firstlist"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOME </li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> SERVICES </li>
    </ul>
   </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense !

Either you choose :
+ **bootstrap 3**
+ **bootstrap 4**
= -------------------> **but not both!**

ditto for jQuery, choose :
+ **jQuery** (with AJAX)
+ **jQuery.slim** (without ajax)
= -----------------------------------> **but not both!**

Obviously you have coded your site to use **Bootstrap 3**.
so here is the procedure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Aurora</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
... and so on...
```

**CSS file:**

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
li.centeredjoin {
  border: 1px solid;
  color: rgb(123, 124, 129);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.joinclass {
  padding: 0em !important;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #95979D;
}
.centeredjoin:hover {
  /* The whole background becomes purple */
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
}
.centeredjoin a:hover {
  color: white !important;
}
```